# Mount a Linux VMDK on Windows 2012 R2

Tags: mount, automation, hyper-v, vhd, powershell-4.0

I would like to mount a Linux VHD (ext3) file on Windows 2012 R2.

So far, I have been using PowerShell to deploy Windows VMs and mount them locally to inject the unattend.xml file. I would like to do the same for the Linux VMs but Windows does not recognize the ext3 format.

Are there any possible ways to do that using the command line or a PowerShell script that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the exe and install it. You can configure this tool to auto-mount the partition. Check this out:

http://www.techgainer.com/how-to-mount-and-access-linux-partitions-ext4ext3ext2-in-windows-explorer-easily/

**Edited**:

This is how you can accomplish this:

```
1) Open disk management --> Action --> More Action and Attach VHD
2) Once you attach the VHD, it will show up in the list as unknown file system
3) Install and open Ext2Fsd
4) You will see your ext2 VHD partition there. Right click on it and "Assign drive letter"
5) Now you can access your Linux partition from Windows Explorer
6) For automount on reboot, go to Tools --> Service management and make sure that the appropriate option is selected.
```

Comment: How would you mount the VHD though?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a third party ext3 driver to be able to open an ext3 filesystem as Windows cannot natively read it. An example: http://www.ext2fsd.com/

Comment: I have seen similar tools to the one that you suggested. I am looking to see if there is a way to install this or a similar driver silently and mount the VM afterwards. I would like to minimize all user interaction.

Comment: Read the downloads page... I believe you can script the installation.